# Two columns from table A contain id's that are stored in a different table B how to select and get the data stored in table B?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have 2 Tables,Table A which has a 2 columns that contain ids and Table B which has the matching ids with movie names. I want to select the row with the movie names not the movie ids such as

Table A

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | name   | favmovieid|   leastfavmovieid       |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
| 101 | Name 1 |     1     |          5              |
| 102 | Name 2 |     6     |          8              |
| 103 | Name 3 |     8     |          6              |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
```

Table B

```
+-------+---------------------+
| movid | namemovie           |
+-------+---------------------+
|  1    | Harry Potter 1      |
|  2    | Harry Potter 2      |
|  3    | Harry Potter 3      |
|  4    | Lord of the Rings 1 |
|  5    | Lord of the Rings 2 |
|  6    | Lord of the Rings 3 |
|  7    | Iron Man 1          |
|  8    | Iron Man 2          |
+-------+---------------------+
```

I have tried to use inner join by inner joining both columns such as

```
Select TableB.namemovie,TableB.namemovie from 
((TableA inner join TableB on TableA.favmovieid=TableB.movid) inner join on TableB TableA.leastfavmovieid=TableB.movid) where TableA.id=101
```

But I get an error saying Table B is mentioned too many times

Then I also tried union as

```
Select TableB.namemovie from (TableA inner join TableB on TableA.favmovieid=TableB.movid)
where TableA.id=101
union 
Select TableB.namemovie from (TableA inner join TableB on TableA.leastfavmovieid=TableB.movid)
where TableA.id=101
```

it does return the two movie names but in two different rows I want to return one row only since I want more information to be returned in that row such as name maybe price or any other column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, the trick is using an alias to reference the table on each join, this should work:

```
select b1.namemovie,b2.namemovie from TableA 
inner join TableB b1 on TableA.favmovieid=b1.movid 
inner join TableB b2 on TableA.leastfavmovieid=b2.movid
where TableA.id=101
```